# How many time and space units does this algorithm take?

Tags: asymptotics

[image]

This is what I counted but I know I'm wrong since my conclusion is not in the choices:

- t = time unit
- s = space unit
- y=1 : 1t & 1s
- for 0 <= i <= N : Nt & 1s
- y=y*i : 2 reads, 1 write, 1 multiplication therefore 4 time units,
  the for loop is thus 4N time units
- total time = 4N+1
- total space = 2 (because there are only two variables that need to be
  stored)

Comment: Although I completly agree with @nir shahar about the weirdness (even poor quality) of the question, please note that 1) $0\leq i \leq N$ is actually a loop of size $N+1$; 2) the creator of the question seems to want you to count the implicit operations within the loop ("the loop is broken down into…").

Comment: Hi @Nathaniel I just posted the answer if you'd like to have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My thoughts about the question

Honestly speaking, this question is *really weird*. Usually when you ask about the time and space complexity, you mean it in big-O or other asymptotical notation. Not the actual literal number of steps the algorithm takes, since this can change depending on the hardware you are using and a lot of other factors.

So the fact that most answers are with the same asymptotics, it makes absolutely no sense!

---

### My answer to the question

The answer depends on what you define a "time unit" and "space unit". Under normal circumstances, you would say this algorithm takes $\Omega(N\log(N))$ time, and would need $\Theta(N\log(N))$ space as well.

The explanation for that comes from the fact that $y$ at the $k$'th iteration is computed to be $k!$ ($k$ factorial). Saving in memory the value $N!$ needs $\log(N!)=\Theta(N\log(N))$ space, and thus also the running time must be **at least** $\Omega(N\log(N))$.

An upper bound for the running time depends on the algorithm used for multiplication.

---

### Your answer to the question

Assuming multiplication takes $O(1)$ time, and a single unit of space is defined as a single variable, your solution is correct. This also demonstrates the problem of not using big-O notation, since your answer is correct however it is not one of the listed answers.

Comment: Hi, I just posted the correct answer. The site even gave me an explanation

Comment: However, I would like you to still read my answer and attempt to understand why the site is wrong in my opinion. Keep in mind that to save a number $k$ in memory you need $\log(k)$ bits.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't realise the system will give me an answer:
[image]